# regular expression to find special character & between xml tags

Tags: java, xml, regex

A xml string generated from another model will pass to me, it may contains some special character such as & in the text of the xml tag.
e.g.

```
<entry>
 <key>state</key>
 <value xsi:type="xs:string">ADDDRESS  3 & ADDR 4, 12345, HONG KONG</value>
</entry>
```

when I build the xml from string will have invalid character error, So I need to escape the special character `&`.
I want to use regex to find the `&` between `<value></value>` tag and replace with the `&amp;`
I have tried some but fail on the regex.

Can anyone give me the some clue on the regex?

besides I use Java 1.6

Comment: There's no chance you can get the originator of the XML to generate something that's valid? Also, is there any chance that the XML will have valid escape sequences (e.g., `&lt;`)--where you would _not_ want to escape the `&`?

Comment: @TedHopp I need to escape < > ' " &, as xml itself already have <> for the tag, so I cannot just simply replace, so need to replace the text in the <value> tag, avoid to replace <> for the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookahead:

Replace

```
&(?!\w*;)(?=[^<]*</value>)
```

by

```
&amp;
```

This works by specifying two lookaheads. The first lookahead `(?!\w*;)` prevents valid HTML escape sequences from being matched. The second lookahead `(?=[^<]*</value>)` specifies that a `</value>` tag must follow the text (after some amount of non-XML-tag content).

Try it [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRiSxKoBDA/index.html).

Comment: @TedHopp: You'll note the lookahead that suppresses matches of valid HTML escape sequences...

Comment: Oops. Nice job. I missed that.

Comment: however, (?<=<value[^>]*>[^>]*)&(?!\w*;) will have compile error. it complains "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: What happens if the closing tag is on the next line (or many lines later)?

Comment: @Scarlett: You need to escape the backslashes to put it in a string. (For clarity, I wrote the expression using normal RegEx syntax, without string escaping)

Comment: @JimGarrison: You'd might need to specify `DOTALL` when matching. However, `[^<]` should already include the newline.

Comment: Face it: attempting to parse [X|HT]ML with regular expressions leads to madness: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18157

Comment: @JimGarrison: The problem is that the input is not well-formed XML. A number of parsers will just barf on seeing a `&` standing by itself. Some massaging is needed to correct the XML first.

Comment: @Scarlett To make it more clear: \ is special character in String. To make it normal \ literal you need to escape it and write as `"\\"`. So to create and pass `\w` to Java's regex engine you need to write it as `"\\w"`.

Comment: @nneonneo : i use str=str.replaceAll("(?<=<value[^>]*>[^>]*)&(?!\\w*;)","&amp;"); to match and replace, while there is error like java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 20
(?<=<value[^>]*>[^>]*)&(?!\w*;)
                    ^

Comment: @Scarlett: check my edit. I replaced the expression with a slightly less problematic one.

Comment: @nneonneo thanks a lot, I tried and successfully replace from <value xsi:type="xs:string">ADDDRESS  3 & ADDR 4, 12345, HONG KONG</value> to 
<value xsi:type="xs:string">ADDDRESS  3 &amp; ADDR 4, 12345, HONG KONG</value>
I will do more tests, ha ...

Comment: @nneonneo it may need a more complicated one, as I also need to replace the < > ' :, original one will also escape the > of <value> tag    <value xsi:type=&quot;xs:string&quot;&gt;ADDDRESS  3 &lt; ADDR 4, 12345, HONG KONG</value>

Comment: Uh, my original expression doesn't do `<>` at all. Are stray `<>` showing up in the value between `<value></value>`? That will definitely get messy.

Comment: @nneonneo yes, <> show up in <value> </value>, but my xml pattern are definitely changeless, the pattern always like <value xsi:type=""> some content may contains < > ' " & </value>

Comment: In order to handle `<` and `>` in between, perhaps the last look-ahead could use a reluctant wildcard: `(?=.*?</value>)`.

Comment: Maybe. But, now I am thinking the easier solution is just to shove the text inside the `<value>` tag in a `CDATA` block. So, you replace `(<value xsi:type="[^"]*">)` with `\1<![CDATA[` and `</value>` with `]]></value>`. This works as long as there aren't any escapes *inside* the `value` tag.

Comment: @nneonneo it nearly reaches the end.<![CDATA[ADDDRESS  3 < ADDR 4, 12345, HONG KONG]]></value>. the <value xsi:type=""> does not replace correctly, what I did is str = str.replaceAll("<value xsi:type=\"[^\"]*\">", "\1<![CDATA[");

Comment: @nneonneo it is wonderful! problem solved! here is my output <value xsi:type="xs:string"><![CDATA[ADDDRESS  3 <>'"& ADDR 4, 12345, HONG KONG]]></value>   appreciate you much!

Comment: Should still die if someone gets clever with a CDATA section that contains a `</value>`.  In other words, it's subject to the "Johnny drop tables" attack. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Yes, if someone uses `</value>` in their address, you die. But, there's literally no way to recover from that if you're given unchangeable non-XML to start.

Comment: Thanks for the remind, actually the xml is the output of a CrossTranslator http://www.etasoft.com/ct.htm, it translates the data from other EDI source to our standard output, while sometimes the source contains some special character such as <>'"&. CrossTranslator cannot turn it to a well-formed xml,as it is treated as String there, then I have to change the invalid part to valid, I cannot use XML parser as when parse it will have exception due to the special char. don't worry about there will be </value> in between the two tags, as it is our interface, unless CrossTranslator translate wrong

Comment: @nneonneo Actually, you could recover from someone putting `</value>` in the address, provided you used standard XML tools, where you specified CDATA sections for the parts that are really character data.  With that in mind, there are tons of "near-XML" handling tools, and "almost-compliant" generators and parsers.  These warnings are really meant for others who see these solutions, as a person of nneonneo's stature likely understands the safety boundaries of his development space (and will sanely stay in them).

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, XML processing requires a context sensitive grammar for proper parsing, which is computationally beyond the ability of regex, which at best can parse items subject to discrete finite automata.

One example which would be impossible for a DFA to properly parse would be:

```
<value xsi:type="xs:string"><value>ADDDRESS  3 & ADDR 4, 12345, HONG KONG</value></value>
```

as the DFA would always wind up returning

```
<value>ADDDRESS  3 & ADDR 4, 12345, HONG KONG
(or possibly)
""
```

while a push-down automata could return two values (depending on the context)

```
<value>ADDDRESS  3 & ADDR 4, 12345, HONG KONG</value>
ADDDRESS  3 & ADDR 4, 12345, HONG KONG
```

In other words, don't use regex to parse XML unless you like bugs.  And by bugs, I mean, really hard bugs to fix, that require rewriting everything to not use regex anyway.

Comment: In this particular instance, the OP just wants to replace some text, which can be done even in the presence of nesting. I've had to do similar hacks to fix broken external XML prior to passing a real parser through it.

Comment: @nneonneo You're more aware of your environment that I, so you do what you have to do.  That said, you know that it is likely to break with the right input, so you get to lie in the bed you made.