# Parsing XML with Special Chars (SQL / CLR)

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, clr

I have looked at most of the parsing of XML into SQL with special Chars and could not find anything relevant that didnt include having control over the XML output itself.
I understand that the way to do this would be make sure all special characters are escaped, the issue i have is that i do not have control over the XML that gets generated until after the fact. The output i could have could be something like the below. I need to find a way to replace all the special characters within the  without touching the characters that are valid for the xml. This could be done using a CLR or in Straight up SQL, i will even consider other options.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<A>
<B>this is my test <myemail@gmail.com</B>
<B>>>>this is another test<<<</B>
</A>
```

Comment: This is not XML. You should re-phrase your question so it is clear that you have some text and you need to parse it in some very particular way (rules not covered in the post yet). The fact that text uses `<` and `>` does not make it XML.

Comment: it is an excerpt from an xml file. (modified to reduce data protection risk)

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep calling that text "XML".... Anyway, something like HtmlAgilityPack may be able to read through it, but don't expect miracles  - "garbage-in garbage-out".

Comment: Andrew, the point that Alexei is making is that what you have is text made to look like XML, but it per the XML definition does not follow XML definitions, and therefore is not XML.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something similar to HtmlEncode() of the contents. Loop through your XML structure and encode the fields you need to prior to writing to the DB, and perform the HtmlDecode() on the read from the DB.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I will give it a shot, i just get the feeling that any xmlreader will through errors when trying to loop through the contents because technically its not valid xml with the special characters in there.

Comment: It's not "technically" invalid XML - it's not XML. You can't use an XML parser  to parse something that's not XML.

Comment: I don't believe this is anywhere close to answer to OP's question that sound like "parse that text file into XML tree"...

Comment: I stand corrected Alexei. I missed the fact that he wasn't controlling the XML, but thought that he was generating the XML himself and needed to encode it at that time.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are sure the XML element names are valid then the solution could be using regular expressions to parse the XML as text and substitute the & with `&amp;` and the > with `&gt;` and < with `&lt;`.
Have a look here [regular expression to find special character & between xml tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326337/regular-expression-to-find-special-character-between-xml-tags) for example.